# Oracle - Excluding certain packages from recompiling using DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Is it possible to exclude certain packages from the DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema command? Even though setting the parameter to FALSE only recompiles invalid objects, I want to be sure that certain packages are forever excluded to prevent dependencies errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a script to generate the compiles exclduing the ones. E.g.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT object_name, object_type 
    FROM user_objects
    WHERE status = 'INVALID'
    AND   object_name NOT IN ( 'EXCL_OBJ1', .... );
  cmd  VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
  FOR r1 IN c1 LOOP
    -- You will need logic here to cater for different 
    -- command e.g. PACKAGE and PACKAGE BODY
    cmd := 'ALTER ' || r1.object_type || ' ' || r1.object_name || ' compile';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cmd;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I usually have a repeat loop to count the invalid objects and exit when the count is the same for 2 consecutive loops.

Note that you will need some logic to cater for different compile command syntax between PACKAGE headers and bodies.